# How can PHP use variables in Underscore template?

Tags: php, backbone.js, underscore.js

I have a web application using backbone/underscore and PHP. All the templates are in php files. For instance, here's a template file:

```
//file template1.php
<script id="template1" type="text/template">
    <label>label 1</label>
    <span id="<%= id %>">span 1</span>
    <?php if ($id > 0): ?>
        //do something
    <?php endif; ?>
</script>
```

id works in <%= id %>, but I try to access the same variable in php (`$id`), it doesn't work -- saying id undefined. So my question is, how can I use that variable in php?
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not how it works.

Try this:

```
<% if (id > 0) { %>
   //do something
<% } %>
```